# Line plus bar chart invalid dates showing in timeline

Tags: nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 [lineplusbarchart](http://nvd3.org/examples/linePlusBar.html). When I have enough data, it shows properly:
[image: line plus bar chart years]
But If I get only few bars (7 bars shows 1970, 8 and more does not), it adds 0 timestamp = year 1970 to my timeline. Is there a way how to easily fix it?
 I probably could generate some 0 height bars before and after existing bars, but that is not very elegant solution. 
[image: two bars with wrong date]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using older version of nvd3 with some mixed up syntax. Here is my [issue](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/865).